# R using extrafont on multiple computers with different system font family names

Tags: r, fonts

I use the package `extrafont` with `ggplot` to produce graphics where all text is in Linux Libertine. I use multiple computers and have a problem because the system font families have different names - "Linux Libertine" and "Linux Libertine G". This means I have to change the name of the font family in my code each time I change computer.

I tried to change the name in the font table from "Linux Libertine G" to "Linux Libertine" so they match, however this results in r not recognising the font.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

The "G" means it's a Linux Libertine variant with [graphite](http://graphite.sil.org/) instructions added. IIRC it's not the upstream version but a fork distributed with LibreOffice.

It should probably be aliased at fontconfig level to the original font name so apps know they should use one for the other when an exact match is unavailable (you have some aliasing fontconfig templates in Fedora "fontpackages" package).

Not sure, however, that R fontconfig support is complete today. If not that will severely limit the font substitution possibilities open to you.